# Storing data obtained from cassandra in spark Memory and make it available to other spark job server jobs in same context

Tags: apache-spark-sql, datastax, datastax-startup

I  am using spark job server and using spark-sql to get data from a cassandra table as follows

```
public Object runJob(JavaSparkContext jsc, Config config) {
  CassandraSQLContext sq = new CassandraSQLContext(JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(jsc));
  sq.setKeyspace("rptavlview");
  DataFrame vadevent = sq.sql("SELECT username,plan,plate,ign,speed,datetime,odo,gd,seat,door,ac from rptavlview.vhistory ");
  vadevent.registerTempTable("history");
  sq.cacheTable("history");
  DataFrame vadevent1 = sq.sql("SELECT plate,ign,speed,datetime FROM history where username='"+params[0]+"' and plan='"+params[1]+"'");
  long count =  vadevent.rdd().count();
  }
```

But I am getting *table not found history*.
Can anybody mention how to cache cassandra data in spark memory and reuse the same data either in concurrent requests of same job or as two jobs one for caching and other for querying.

I am using dse5.0.4  so spark version is 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

You can allow spark jobs to share the state of other contexts.  This [link](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/contexts.md#custom-contexts-and-context-specific-jobs) goes more in depth.

Comment: I could see a scala version of SqlLoaderJob where shared sqlcontext  is used. Could you suggest any Java Example for the same. Is it available in new version of Spark- 2.1?